# add variable as covariate or weights?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Let's say I have an experiment in which I count the number of times mice successfully press a lever (`scores`).

```
scores <- c(5, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 13, 13, 14, 22,
            4, 9, 4, 4, 5, 9, 7, 14, 4, 14,
            5, 1, 7, 10, 10, 15, 23, 23, 30, 23, 
            12, 16, 15, 16, 37, 18, 21, 20, 21, 25, 
            23, 27, 47, 27, 24, 59, 9, 23, 21, 24, 
            6, 8, 8, 8, 11, 11, 14, 14, 15, 21,
            1, 4, 6, 7, 5, 12, 15, 14, 12, 13,
            12, 12, 11, 16, 17, 18, 21, 20, 23, 25,
            8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21,
            5, 3, 2, 10, 10, 5, 3, 5, 3, 13,
            2, 4, 7, 7, 8, 12, 15, 19, 19, 23,
            1, 1, 3, 2, 8, 12, 13, 16, 23, 23)
dat <- data.frame(
       id=rep(c("id01","id02","id03","id04","id05","id06","id07","id08","id09","id10","id11","id12"), each=10), 
       score=scores,
       day=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),times=12), 
       perf=rep(c(10,15,12,35,34,156,12,90,10,22,23,120),each=10))
```

I expect `score` to increase across `day`. However, I would also like to adjust the individual estimates (as given by `ranef(fm)$Subject`) depending on the mice's performance on a previous but related experiment (`perf`).

For example, `id01` and `id06` behave similar across days, but `id06` has a much better `perf` and should be accounted for by the model.

I thought of using `perf` either as a covariate:

```
fm1 <- lmer(score ~ day + perf + (day|id), dat)
```

or as weights:

```
fm2 <- lmer(score ~ day + (day|id), weights=perf, dat)
```

Is any of these options doing what I intend to achieve?

Comment: This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168958/119085) goes a bit deeper on how these weights are used in the log-likelihood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `weights` argument typically refers to case weights, either the number of units that shared that set of covariate values or the estimated precision (inverse of variance) for the observation. So your second model doesn't do what you want.

Your first model *adjusts* for what your want; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/439354/28500) for a similar situation.

As your outcomes are counts, however, you shouldn't be using standard linear regression with `lmer()`. Use a model appropriate for count data, like `glmer()` with a Poisson model or a negative binomial model. That seemed to work well when I tried it on your sample data.